# Changing variable values between two daughter classes in java

Tags: java

I have two classes, each one extends the same class,
what i am trying to do is change another class attribute value as i call a method from the other class. Here's what i have:

```
public class Termometro extends Equipamentos{

    public Termometro(String nome, int id) {
        super(nome, id);
    }
```

-

```
public class ArCondicionado extends Equipamentos{

    public ArCondicionado(String nome, int id) {
        super(nome, id);
    }
```

And by calling this method in the ArCondicionado class:

```
@Override
public void setValor(double valor) {
    super.setValor(valor);//change the atribute "valor" value of the termometro class here.
}
```

Comment: You need to have some reference to both child classes in the parent class. Then, when you do your `super` call, have some logic in the parent class that updates the other class as well.

Comment: If the value is always shared between all child classes you can use a static field

Answer (score 0):

Use the `static` field that shares the value with all the instances of the class.

```
public class Equipamentos {

    public static double valor;

    protected String nome;
    protected int id;

}
```

Then you change the value with `Equipamentos.valor = value;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a reference of Termometro in your ArCondicionado class. Then all you would have to do is call the method referencing it:

```
public class ArCondicionado extends Equipamentos {

     private Termometro termometro;

     @Override
     public void setValor(double valor) {
          termometro.setValor(valor);
     }
}
```

Comment: I think it works, the thing is when i call it, it gives me this error: java.lang.NullPointerException.
I don't see where the null value is coming from.

Comment: Then maybe you should make sure the termometer is instantiated in the constructor.